# When is it time to switch to NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mariadb, database, nosql

I am dealing with a large database that is collecting historical pricing data.  The schema is relatively simple and does not change.

Something like:

SKU (char), type(enum), price(double), datetime(datetime)

The issue is that this table now has over 500,000,000 rows and is around 20gb and growing.  It is already getting a bit difficult to run queries.  One common query is to get all skus from a specific date range consisting of maybe 500,000 records.  Add any complexity like group by, and you can forget it.

This db is mostly writes.  But we obviously need to crunch the data and run queries occasionally.  I understand that better index planning can help speed up the queries, but I am wondering if this is the type of data that would benefit from a noSQL solution like MongoDB?  Can I expect mysql (probably moving to MariaDB) to continue to work for us, even after it grows beyond 100-200 gb in size? Or should I explore alternatives before things get unweildly?

Answer (score 4):

NoSQL is not a solution to a "large database" problem; NoSQL--specifically document databases--are designed for scenarios where the nature of the data you're storing varies, so you don't want to define rigid schemas and relationships up front.

What you have is simple, well-defined data. This is ideally suited for a relational database, but for something of that scale I would recommend looking something either commercial (i.e. SQL Server or Oracle, depending on your platform). The databases I work with in SQL Server are around four terabytes in size with several tables in the hundreds-of-millions records like you have. A relational database can easily accommodate the simple data you've outlined.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have an ideal use-case for SQL, and a rather bad fit for NoSQL. MySQL devs report people using databases of 5,000,000,000 records. Some other SQL servers will be even more scalable than that. However, if you don't have a proper index support, it should be impossible to manage even a fraction of that.

BTW, what is your table schema, including indices?

Comment: Innodb - id (int,primary), SKU (char), type(enum), price(double), datetime(datetime), also, since I need to be able to sort or run queries based on any of those fields, I have recently created a single index on each one.  Previously it was just id and sku.

Comment: Each query can only use only one index per table; so if you have a WHERE and a GROUP BY, it is very likely your indices do not cover everything; you most likely will need a composite index or three. Can't say more without seeing the exact query.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to mariadb and then use the spider engine. The spider engine makes it possible to split your data across multiple mariadb instances without loosing the abillity to run queries against your existing instance.

So you can define your own rules for partitioning and then create one instance per partition. So in the end you have multiple instances of mariadb but all your records are virtual sumed up in one table with the spider engine.

Your performace gain would be because you split your data across multiple instances and therefore reduce the amount of records per table or instance and of course by using more hardware ressources.